# need at least 5 volts but 3.7 lithium polymer battery does not supply enough Voltage

Tags: arduino-nano, voltage-level, voltage, voltage-protection, lipo

I am building a device using an Arduino Nano, an OLED display and infrared thermometer sensor. I want to make it rechargeable so I am using a 1 cell lipo battery and a tp4056 circuit protection board, which cuts power at 4.2 V and 2.5 V. The OLED runs in the 5.0 V port and the sensor runs in the 3.3 V port in the Arduino. Of course the system does not work since the battery only delivers 3.7 V and when I measure the voltage in the Nano, it is actually seeing around 2.6 volts in each port (I'm assuming this drop is due to internal resistance of the cables and the protection circuit). Having said that I was thinking about using a boost converter but everything I find online says that the input voltage for the boost converter should be at least 3.5 V for it to deliver a constant 5.0 V output. This would not work since as I mentioned, the protection circuit will cut the power at 2.5 V which is well below the 3.5 V mark. Is there another practical solution I could use for this system to work with 1 cell lipo battery. I don't want to use 2 cell battery pack since it would make it more expensive and bigger in size. Also, I ran the project with a 9.0 V battery and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why the typical [LiPO battery shield](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Battery-Shield/) includes a boost converter.

I'm not sure where you saw the unusually high (3.5V) low-voltage limit, but that isn't typical of most converters.

Comment: Correction I meant 3 V, but this still does not solve the problem since the tp4056 cuts power at 2.8 volts according to data sheet. Please do correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you perceive the "problem" to be. Most boost regulators will shut down once they can no longer maintain regulation. If this happens at a voltage that is higher than the level that would actually cause battery damage, that isn't really a problem -- it actually helps extend the overall life of the battery, even if the amount of use per charge is slightly less.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a display that does not require 5v to run.  Using a lower voltage display like an led based one will simplify the system.  My favorite thing to use is the adafruit feather huzzah8266 with the charlieplex display board on top.  They fit together via header pins and it has a built in lipo charging circuit and battery connector.  You can then wire your sensor in and voila.
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2821
https://www.adafruit.com/product/3134